# Typeahead.js with Tags is not firing remote request

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I have a web page. In this page, I'm using:

- Bootstrap 3,
- bootstrap-tagsinput (0.8.0)
- bootstrap3-typeahead (v4.0.1)
- typeahead.js (0.11.1)

In my web page, I have the following ([Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lu9049L/)):

```
<input id="MyChoices" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" // Initialize the tag piece 
$('#MyChoices').tagsinput({
  typeaheadjs: {
    source: suggestions,
    afterSelect: function() {
      this.$element[0].value = '';
    }
  }
});autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" value="" />
// Connect the lookup endpoint
var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  sufficient: 3,
  remote: {
    url: '/api/suggestions/find'
  }
});
```

For some reason, it never fires a request to my server to get the suggestions. I have fiddler open and I do not see anything coming across as I enter things into the text field. At the same time, I do not see any JavaScript errors in the console window. For that reason, it seems like I have something configured incorrectly. Yet, everything looks correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know you said Fiddler reported no network traffic, but have you checked the `Network` tab in Chrome? Maybe there's some browser level filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might had a problem with the order of the scripts.

The order the browser loads the javascript files is very important.

```js
// Connect the lookup endpoint
var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  sufficient: 3,
  remote: {
    url: '/api/suggestions/find'
  }
});

// Initialize the tag piece 
$('#MyChoices').tagsinput({
  typeaheadjs: {
    source: suggestions,
    afterSelect: function() {
      this.$element[0].value = '';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput-typeahead.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input id="MyChoices" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" value="" />
```

> Note that the code will do nothing, but if you will check with chrome's Developers Tools you will see the request to `/api/suggestions/find`